# Using linq fill a class from another class

Tags: c#, linq

I have an MVC5 application on which i am working on.

I have a situation in the app where i have to find distinct elements from a list but with a little tweak.

Let me explain the scenario.

I have a Product and Category class:-

```
**Product**

ProductId
ProducName
CategoryId
CategoryName
```

---

```
**Category**

CategoryId
CategoryName
```

I have multiple products so i am dealing with a list of Products:-

```
List<Product> listProducts = new List<Product>();
```

All the products can be in same category or in multiple categories. So i want to get all the distinct categories list in the category class.

To find the Distinct categories we can use linq as following:-

var listProductCategories = listProducts.Select(x => x.CategoryName).Distinct().ToList();

But this would return a List and i want List with both CategoryId and CategoryName.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `CategoryId` and `CategoryName` and then project to a new `Category` item like:

```
var query = listProducts.GroupBy(r => new { r.CategoryId, r.CategoryName })
            .Select(grp => new Category
            {
                CategoryId = grp.Key.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = grp.Key.CategoryName
            });
```

You can add `ToList` at the end of your query if you want to get a `List<Category>`

Answer (score 1):

Below is the query based on your questions.
This query will returns distinct records if the list have the similar records.

```
 List<Product> listProducts1 = new List<Product>();

 var productNames = listProducts.Select(prod => new { CategoryId = prod.CategoryId, CategoryName = prod.CategoryName }).Distinct();

//This query would returns distict records based on the Category class data.

Category cat=new Category();

var productNames2 = listProducts.Where(prod => prod.CategoryId == cat.CategoryId).Select(prod => new { CategoryId = prod.CategoryId, CategoryName = prod.CategoryName }).Distinct();
```